# Ошибка вызова функции класса php

Tags: php, laravel

Вот код

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class bitcoincourse extends Controller
{

    public function kraken()
    {
        $course = json_decode(getResource('https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XBTUSD'),'TRUE');
        return $course['result']['XXBTZUSD']['c'][0];
    }

    public function getResource($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        // SET CURL OPTIONS
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        // SIMPLE HACK FOR HTTPS SUPPORT, IDEALLY, WOULD POINT CURL TO A *PEM FILE WITH CERTS.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $course = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $course;
    }

    public function index()
    { 
        return kraken();
    }
}
?>
```

Хочу вызвать функцию `kraken()`, но получаю ошибку:

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\kraken()

Comment: Потому что вызывать надо  $this->kraken()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут даже не в ларавеле дело, при вызове метода внутри класса объекта, нужно использовать `$this`

```
$this->kraken();
```